# SSRS Automate Export of Report for Each Parameter Value

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a report in SSRS that has one parameter named Employee Name that allows the viewer to filter the report by employee. The parameter is a drop down that has approx 500 employees in the list. I need to export the report for each employee in the drop down (in PDF or Excel). So, if I did this manually as an example, I'd select employee #1 from the drop down, then go to the export drop down menu and select PDF to save it as a file for employee #1 results. Then, I'd repeat this for all 500 employees.

Is there a way to automate this in SSRS? Or another way.

Comment: Write a small piece of code in your favourite language to iterate through all staff members and run the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you’re describing is a Data Driven Subscription. Create a subscription, pick “data driven” rather than standard, and in the dataset you’re prompted for, list all the employees. Then tell it to populate the parameter using a value from that dataset. Easy!

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you can roll your own to programmatically render the report for each parameter.

Comment: ...in which case I’d recommend Invoke-WebRequest in PowerShell, using SSRS via URL Access.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to generate the SSRS report in an excel file for each parameter value dynamically? Thanks in advance.